# Cannot find reference 'mobileby' in '__init__.py'

Tags: python, appium, appium-android, python-appium

[image]

Cannot find reference 'mobileby' in '**init**.py' cant fix this error while trying to run appium with python code

Comment: Which version are you using; Based on the [docs](https://appium.github.io/python-client-sphinx/webdriver.common.html#webdriver.common.mobileby.MobileBy), `MobileBy` was deprecated in v2.1.0. "Please use ‘from `appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy` instead of `MobileBy`."

Comment: I already this ans using by but I facing another issue
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'

Comment: if you could advice

Comment: So that fixes your import error, but your new error is out the scope of the current question and it's a different issue entirely